# How to debug a Gulp task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, gulp

How do I debug a gulp task defined in my `gulpfile.js` with a debugger such as the Google Chrome debugger, stepping through the task's code line by line?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

With Node.js version 6.3+ you can use the [`--inspect` flag](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js) when running your task.

To debug a gulp task named `css`:

1. Find out where your gulp executable lives. If gulp is installed locally, this will be at `node_modules/.bin/gulp`. If gulp is installed globally, run `which gulp` (Linux/Mac) or `where gulp` (Windows) in a terminal to find it.
2. Run one of these commands according to your version of Node.js. If required, replace `./node_modules/.bin/gulp` with the path to your gulp installation from step 1.

   - Node.js 6.3+: `node --inspect --debug-brk ./node_modules/.bin/gulp css`
   - Node.js 7+: `node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/gulp css`
3. Use Chrome to browse to `chrome://inspect`.

The `--debug-brk` (Node.js 6.3+) and `--inspect-brk` (Node.js 7+) flags are used to pause code execution on the first line of code of your task. This gives you a chance to open up the Chrome debugger and set breakpoints before the task finishes.

If you don't want the debugger to pause on first line of code, just use the `--inspect` flag.

You can also install the [Node.js Inspector Manager (NIM)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj) extension for Chrome to help with step 3. This will automatically open up a Chrome tab with the debugger ready to go, as an alternative to manually browsing to a URL.

Comment: Once loaded, add a breakpoint in gulp.js after `require(env.configPath);` - that loads your gulpfile, so you can find it in Sources and add breakpoints.

Comment: Just go to `chrome://inspect`, you don't need to know the devtools address

Comment: With newer versions of node now, the node flags have been consolidated into just `--inspect-brk`

Comment: I had to use `./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js` instead of `./node_modules/.bin/gulp`

Comment: Another way to set breakpoints (besides @TrueWill's): use _Add folder to workspace_ in the _Sources_ tab, now you can select whichever file you have your task defined in, and then set the breakpoints as you wish.

Answer (score 20):

For anyone using VS Code 1.10+

1. Open the debug panel.
2. Click on the settings icon.
3. Click on *Add Configuration* button.
4. Choose Node.js: Gulp Task.

This is how your launch.json file should look.

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Gulp task",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js",
      "args": [
        "yourGulpTaskName"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this example!

Comment: When using VS Code to add a new build configuration there is a _Node.js: Gulp task_ template you can choose. It will insert a new configuration that looks like the code above. No need to copy and paste :)

Comment: ok, so this is the config - but how can I start with debugging?

Comment: I don't know why but with this configuration I cannot set breakpoints. The method of adding `console.log(...)` statements in my code worked instead.

Comment: Maybe it was related to the fact that my Gulfile was named `Gulpfile.js` because I renamed it `gulpfile.js` and now breakpoints are trigerred (I'm on Windows with VS Code 1.45.1).

Comment: Little problem with this configuration is that output of the task is only in VSCode's debug console. To have gulp task running in terminal with full output you need to add `"console": "integratedTerminal",` to this configuration.
BTW Currenty (vscode v.1.50) it uses `"type": "pwa-node"` by default.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using webstorm you can right click the task in the gulp panel and select debug.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Thanks user2943490, on Windows I found this version worked for me:

```js
node --inspect --debug-brk ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --verbose
```

Comment: thanks, targeting ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js helped me out

Answer (score 4):

If you are using gulp-nodemon you can do this in your gulpfile.
Just pass it the execMap option:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
    nodemon({
        script: 'server.js',
        ext: 'js',
        execMap: {
            js: "node --inspect"
        }
    })
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Version   (node v8.11.3,  npm 6.2.0,   gulp 3.9.1)

Windows 10 & git bash

Install [Node.js V8 --inspector Manager (NiM)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj) & set to your [preference](https://www.screencast.com/t/kSznAKPRkh)

Try this:

```
node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the answer of @Avi Y. but I suppose people would had appreciated a more complete script :

```
gulp.task('nodemon', ['sass'], function(cb) {
var started = false;
    consoleLog('nodemon started');
return nodemon({
    //HERE REMOVE THE COMMENT AT THE BEGINING OF THE LINE YOU NEED
    //exec: 'node --inspect --debug-brk node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js', 
    exec: 'node --inspect --debug-brk',
    //exec: 'node --inspect',
    script: path.server,
    ignore: ['*/gulpfile.js', 'node_modules/*'],
    verbose: true
}).on('start', function() {
    if (!started) {
        cb();
        started = true;
    }
}).on('restart', function() {
    consoleLog('nodemon restarted the server');
});});
```