# LESS @plugin Debugging (node)

Tags: node.js, plugins, less

Does anyone know how to debug a less plugin when using node to compile? So that I would be able to see the value of console.log() within custom less functions.

I am also using gulp-less. I have tried to run the gulp this way:

```
node --inspect --debug-brk /usr/local/bin/gulp compilecss
```

This ran the gulp task but I don't see any console from within the function inside the javascript @plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned method worked, the issue was that the plugin wasn't set up correctly. For those who were in my shoes this is what worked:

Follow the instructions on this answer for getting the inspector in the gulp task.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033298/how-to-debug-a-gulp-task)

Then if your plugin is installed you should see logs in the console from the less custom plugin or it's functions.